# Проблема с несоответствием типов на iOS, Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, coredata

Есть приложение, которое имеет список сотрудников, и у каждого сотрудника может быть несколько задач. При нажатии на сотрудника должны открываться его задачи. Тут появляется ошибка:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for
>   to-many relationship: property = "task"; desired type = NSSet; given
>   type = _PFArray; value =

Код для контроллера сотрудников:

```
#import "EmployeesViewController.h"
#import "Tasks.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import CoreData;
#import "Employees.h"
#import "TasksViewController.h"

@interface EmployeesViewController ()
@property(strong) NSMutableArray *employees;
@end

@implementation EmployeesViewController

-(NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext{

    NSManagedObjectContext *context=nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context=[delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Employees"];
    self.employees=[[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];       
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"empToTasks"]){

        TasksViewController *task = segue.destinationViewController;
        task.emp = [self.employees objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    return 1;
}



-(BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return YES;

}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (editingStyle==UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [context deleteObject:[self.employees objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSError *error=nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Не удалось! %@ ", error);
            return;
        }

        [self.employees removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }


}



-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.employees.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSManagedObject *employees = [self.employees objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText: [employees valueForKey: @"name"]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[employees valueForKey:@"position"]];
    return cell;
}  
@end
```

Код для контроллера задачи:

```
    #import "TasksViewController.h"
#import "Tasks.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@import CoreData;
#import "EmployeesViewController.h"

@interface TasksViewController ()

@end

@implementation TasksViewController


-(NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext{

    NSManagedObjectContext *context=nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context=[delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Tasks"];
    self.emp.task=[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}



-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    return 1;
}



-(BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return YES;

}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.emp.task.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell1";
    UITableViewCell*cell1 =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    NSManagedObject *tasks = [self.emp.task.allObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell1.textLabel setText: [tasks valueForKey: @"task"]];
    return cell1;
}
```

Ошибка содержится здесь:

```
 NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Tasks"];
    self.emp.task=[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: В вопросе вы привели слишком много не нужного кода и при этом не показали из чего у вас состоит модель и как она связана между собой

Comment: {NSManagedObjectContext  * managedObjectContext =  [ self managedObjectContext ]; 
    NSFetchRequest  * fetchRequest =  [[ NSFetchRequest alloc ] initWithEntityName :@ "Tasks" ]; 
    self . emp . task =[ managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest : fetchRequest ошибка : ноль ]; 
    [ собственная личность . Tableview reloadData ];} вот здесь у меня ошибка

Comment: Эм ошибка то может у вас в этом месте генерируется, но сама проблема в другом месте. Тот код, который вы привели, по нему невозможно понять что у вас происходит в проекте. ps можете прикрепить файл с проектом - я его посмотрю

Comment: @TikhonovAlexander подскажите пожалуйста, что вам показать или что объяснить что бы было понятнее

Comment: Судя по содержанию это тестовый проект, залейте его куда-нибудь, я скачаю и посмотрю код.

Comment: @TikhonovAlexander https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxSMtqa62EX9RVIzcWtCaktpM0E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, действительно, ошибка была в том месте, где вы указали, но без представления модели это было сложно понять.

```
[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Возвращает массив задач, то есть NSArray.
А модель `Employees` имеет проперти множество, то бишь  `NSSet<Tasks *> *task;`

Соответсвенно такой кусок кода ведет к ошибке

```
self.emp.tasks = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]; // Error
```

Правильный вариант представлен ниже

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Tasks"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *allTasks = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (error == nil ) {
    NSLog(@"Success: Resulting array of tasks:\n%@", allTasks);
    self.emp.task = [NSSet setWithArray:allTasks];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Failure: something went wrong: %@", error);
}
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Так же будьте осторожны с добавлением новых элементов в emp.tasks.
`self.emp.task.addObject()` приведет к ошибке.

Если мне не изменяет память, то добавление делается путем копирования старого `NSSet`, добавления нового `Task` в этот `NSSet` и присвоением `self.emp.tasks = newSet;`